# Titlesec, paragraph title disappears using \titleformat

Tags: titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I am using th `titlesec` package to redefine paragraphs (as well as a few minor changes). Essentially, I just want to change the format from bold to italic font. Here's my code:

```
    \usepackage[compact,
        explicit]{titlesec}
        \titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{2pt}{}
```

While LaTeX compiles just fine, the paragraph title disappears when the `\titleformat{...` command is used. Instead, there is just a blank space.

I tried the example command from Standard Classes in the titlesec manual (p. 23):

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
```

which gives the same error, i.e. the title disappears.

Comment: It seems the error is due to specifying global options for the package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From page 4 of the manual: Titles disappear due to the global `explicit` option. When `explicit` is called globally, the title must be given explicitly with #1. That is:

```
\usepackage[compact,
    explicit]{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{2pt}{#1}{}
```

Comment: Can this be locally overridden?